# Scrape function only returns one of the links instead of all of the products im trying to get

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Im really new to node.js and puppeteer.
Im trying to get all the links of the products when I search for them and save them but it only saves the first one and not the others. I dont know if my selectors are wrong or if the code is wrong.

```
const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/busca/?ft=pepsi',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);
        // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
        await page.waitForSelector('.wrapper > .main');
        // Get the link to all the required products
        let urls = await page.$$eval('section > div.coleccion-prods > div > div.vitrine.resultItemsWrapper', links => { 
             
            links = links.filter(link => link.querySelector('.marca').textContent !== "PEPSI")
            //Extract the links from the data
            links = links.map(el => el.querySelector('h3 > a').href)
            return links;

        });
        console.log(urls);
        
    }
}

module.exports = scraperObject;
```

node.js vrs. 18.1.0

puppeteer vrs. 14.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import ppt from 'puppeteer';

const url = 'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/busca/?ft=pepsi';
const selectors = {
  main: '.wrapper > .main',
  productLink: "//div[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/h3/a/@href",
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await ppt.launch({
    headless: true,
    devtools: false,
    args: [
      '--window-size=1600,1200',
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-infobars',
      '--window-position=0,0',
      '--ignore-certifcate-errors',
      '--ignore-certifcate-errors-spki-list',
    ],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582');
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector(selectors.main);
  await page.waitForXPath(selectors.productLink, { timeout: 3000 });
  const handles = await page.$x(selectors.productLink);
  const links = await Promise.all(handles.map((h) => h.evaluate((elm) => elm.textContent)));
  await browser.close();
  console.log(links);
})();
```

```
[
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-3-lts-120091/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-500-ml-56079/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-black-15-lts-247793/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-black-225-lts-239383/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-pepsi-black-lata-354-cc-275841/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-light-225-lts-108411/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-pepsi-cola-225-lts-199640/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-en-lata-354-ml-68235/p',
  'https://diaonline.supermercadosdia.com.ar/gaseosa-cola-pepsi-15-lts-39692/p'
]
```

If I may suggest, take a look at `XPath` selectors. They are much more versatile than standard css selectors.

Comment: Ohh, almost forgot. Open the devtools in chrome and go to the elements page press `Ctrl + F` and paste `//div[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/h3/a/@href` in the input. You will see the power of XPath